# How to configure geckodriver with log level as trace through firefox_options?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I try to run selenium on VPS to run tests in python. I've got some python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.log.level = 'trace'
selenium = Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

And I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/testy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/testy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/testy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/testy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/testy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Firefox starts but, it is avaible after python throws an exception, and its useless by that.

geckodriver.log says that

```
1540423460336   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
1540423460465   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:34241
1540423461245   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.MmPzTonVHFIu"
1540423461272   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:36731
1540423475244   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification "profile-after-change"
1540423476412   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification "command-line-startup"
1540423476412   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
1540423514528   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification "sessionstore-windows-restored"
1540423521297   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
1540423524134   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on activity-stream@mozilla.org: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsINavHistoryService.removeObserver]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://activity-stream/lib/PlacesFeed.jsm :: removeObservers :: line 220"  data: no] Stack trace: removeObservers()@resource://activity-stream/lib/PlacesFeed.jsm:220 < onAction()@resource://activity-stream/lib/PlacesFeed.jsm:257 < _middleware/</<()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:51 < Store/this[method]()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:30 < uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:153 < uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/ActivityStream.jsm:274 < uninit()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:80 < shutdown()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:196 < callBootstrapMethod()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4419 < observe()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2279
Promise rejected after context unloaded: Message manager disconnected
1540423541320   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref apz.content_response_timeout to 60000
1540423541388   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.download.panel.shown to true
1540423541390   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.EULA.override to true
1540423541390   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.newtabpage.enabled to false
1540423541598   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.newtabpage.introShown to true
1540423541598   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.offline to false
1540423541598   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.pagethumbnails.capturing_disabled to true
1540423541630   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.search.update to false
1540423541688   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled to false
1540423541822   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.tabs.disableBackgroundZombification to false
1540423541822   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs to false
1540423541822   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.tabs.warnOnOpen to false
1540423541822   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL to 
1540423541824   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.urlbar.suggest.searches to false
1540423541960   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref browser.urlbar.userMadeSearchSuggestionsChoice to true
1540423542166   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted to false
1540423542166   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref dom.disable_open_during_load to false
1540423542166   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref dom.file.createInChild to true
1540423542168   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref dom.max_chrome_script_run_time to 0
1540423542208   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref dom.max_script_run_time to 0
1540423542320   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled to false
1540423542320   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref extensions.webservice.discoverURL to http://%(server)s/dummy/discoveryURL
1540423542320   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref network.http.prompt-temp-redirect to false
1540423542320   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref network.http.speculative-parallel-limit to 0
1540423542320   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false
1540423542322   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref security.notification_enable_delay to 0
1540423542322   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref signon.autofillForms to false
1540423542322   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref signon.rememberSignons to false
1540423542372   Marionette  DEBUG   New connections are accepted
1540423542372   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 36731
console.error: 
  Message: Error: SessionFile is closed
  Stack:
    write@resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionFile.jsm:385:29
write@resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionFile.jsm:73:12
_writeState@resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionSaver.jsm:363:12
_saveState@resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionSaver.jsm:301:12
_saveStateAsync@resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionSaver.jsm:347:5
saveStateAsyncWhenIdle@resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionSaver.jsm:198:9

1540423545096   addons.productaddons    WARN    Failed downloading XML, status: 0, reason: error
1540423545192   addons.productaddons    WARN    Failed downloading via XHR, status: 0, reason: error
1540423546620   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification "xpcom-shutdown"
1540423546622   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref apz.content_response_timeout
1540423546622   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.download.panel.shown
1540423546622   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.EULA.override
1540423546622   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.newtabpage.enabled
1540423546724   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.newtabpage.introShown
1540423546724   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.offline
1540423546724   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.pagethumbnails.capturing_disabled
1540423546724   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.search.update
1540423546724   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled
1540423546726   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.tabs.disableBackgroundZombification
1540423546726   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs
1540423546726   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.tabs.warnOnOpen
1540423546726   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL
1540423546726   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.urlbar.suggest.searches
1540423546866   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref browser.urlbar.userMadeSearchSuggestionsChoice
1540423547056   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted
1540423547056   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref dom.disable_open_during_load
1540423547056   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref dom.file.createInChild
1540423547056   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref dom.max_chrome_script_run_time
1540423547056   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref dom.max_script_run_time
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref extensions.webservice.discoverURL
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref network.http.prompt-temp-redirect
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref network.http.speculative-parallel-limit
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref security.notification_enable_delay
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref signon.autofillForms
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   Resetting recommended pref signon.rememberSignons
1540423547172   Marionette  DEBUG   New connections will no longer be accepted
```

Can you tell me, do you know other debug methods for case like that?
I'am using
python 2.7

selenium 3.14.1

firefox 59.0.2 (the same error is produced by ff62)

geckodriver 0.21 (the same error is produced by 0.23)

Comment: a 500 error indicates that the server(page) crashed trying to process your request.... it has nothing to do with selenium and we are not going to be able to help solve it without seeing the server log or at a minimum seeing your actual code (not your logfiles)

Comment: but this is code (python snippet), which producess this error. This is on firefox initialization. this 500 error comes from selenium server. At this momemnt I even do any get driver.get stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of [selenium.webdriver.firefox.options](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.options) of *Selenium Python Client v3.14.0* you need to use:

```
class selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Log
```

Example Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Log

log = Log()
log.level = "TRACE"
options = Options()
options.add_argument(log.level)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options,executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

Comment: you are only using Log() to store  string?

Comment: thanks, that gave me the reason of 500. Funny thing is that, as always after reboot everything works.

Comment: Hello! thank you! what would be for the new version?